# MSSQL server not allow to take backup with user schema

Tags: sql-server, export, backup, bacpac

> One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used a part of data a package,
>
> Error  SQL71510: Error validating element [myuser]: Sql User:[myuser] has unresolved reference to sqlLogin [myuser].

We cannot take a backup due to this user schema element.

How to take a backup without user-schema or any alternatives?
Do we need to add any other privileges to back-up this database?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. It looks like you have an orphaned `USER` and so the Bacpac is failing. Have you attempted making the `USER` not an orphan or not related to a `LOGIN` at all?

Comment: Also [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) I have just gone ahead and removed the image, as at least some of the errors are in text in your question.

Comment: Also a .bacpac is not a backup, it's a logical extract of the objects and data.  If you want a backup, take a backup. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15  A backup is a physcical copy, and so won't complain about stuff like this.